# Probabilistic latent semantic analysis - objective function

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, latent-variable, latent-semantic-analysis

In pLSA we are trying to maximize a likelihood function.
The likelihood function can be given as:

$L = \Pi_i^N \Pi_j^M P(d_i,w_j)^{n(d_i,w_j)}$

Where, M is the number of words and N is the number of documents.

I didnt understand this objective function. Here are we trying to maximize the likelihood $P(w|d)$? Could you please explain this objective function (derivation).

I didnt understand the power $n(d_i,w_j)$ in the equation. How it came there?

Comment: This looks like the multinomial likelihood to me.